# How Do I Use A Targeted Mouse-Click Function with Love2D?

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make it so that if a user clicks the left mouse button at 200x300 then a variable will be changed. I searched online for tutorials but cannot find a solution.

```lua
function love.load()
    medium = love.graphics.newFont(45)
    small = love.graphics.newFont(25)
    micro = love.graphics.newFont(14)

    StartGame = false
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
    love.graphics.setFont(small)
    love.graphics.print("Play", 200, 300)
end

function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
    if love.mousepressed( 200, 300, 'l' ) then
        StartGame = true
    end
end

function love.mousereleased(x, y, button)
end

function love.quit()
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This will set the variable when the user clicks down at 200, 300

```
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
   if button == "l" and x == 200 and y == 300 then
       StarGame = true
   end
end
```

But that is likely to be too demanding on the user to select a single point perfectly. So the code below adds 10 pixels around the point (200, 300) to make it easier to click.

```
local function inCircle(cx, cy, radius, x, y)
    local dx = cx - x
    local dy = cy - y
    return dx * dx + dy * dy <= radius * radius
end


function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
   if button == "l" and inCircle(200, 300, 10, x, y) then
      StartGame = true
   end
end
```

Try changing `10` to find what feels right.

Answer (score 1):

to select a single point perfectly use of the below code

```
 function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
   if button == 1 and x>200 and x<230 and y>280 and y<320 then
   StartGame = true
end
end
```